# How do I assign a mac to an ethernet port in DHCPCD

Tags: linux, networking, router, raspberry-pi, mac-address

I am running a Raspberry Pi Zero with two usb connected ethernet ports (different models, different MACs). When I cold boot MAC A is assigned to eth0 and MAC B is assigned to eth1. after a reboot MAC A is assigned to eth1 and MAC B is assigned to eth0. MAC A is connected to my Jetpack and it's IP is assigned by the Jetpack. MAC B is supposed to be static and is itself a DHCP server. The Raspberry Pi is being used as a bridge to convert my USB Jetpack to ethernet and source internet for my home network. (My router does not allow usb as an lan connection.) Any suggestions besides replacing the router, which I am thinking of anyway, but this is also a learning experience. Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think a better way to phrase the question might be, "How can I get two USB Ethernet dongles to each always get assigned the same interface identifier (eth0 vs. eth1) every time under Raspbian".

Comment: Does this answer help? https://superuser.com/questions/1431018/network-interface-names-via-udev-for-usb-nics

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking the wrong question.

MAC's are not assigned by DHCP Servers.  (DHCP Servers look at MACS and assign IP addresses and other attributes - but not the interface).

I imagine it depends on the OS/Distro you are running on the Pi, but the solution is to fix the way devices are enumerated.  Very often this is done by UDEV rules.  I believe this is done in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules in Raspian

Also see https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=278522

Comment: He isn't asking for the DHCP server to do anything. He wants to be able to configure his **DHCP C**lient **D**aemon (DHCPCD) in a stable way, but can't because USB enumeration is leaving him with unstable device identifiers (the "eth0" name doesn't always point at the same USB Ethernet dongle after reboot).

Comment: Oops now I see the second half of your answer is on the right track but I can't remove my downvote. Maybe if you remove the bit about DHCP Servers I'll be able to remove the downvote.